# How to use sqlachemy to set limit to 20% of the dataset

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

How to do it without calculating by hand using panda?

SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0.1*COUNT(*) FROM table

This code above does not work anyway.

Comment: Do you mean to (random) sample, or take the first 20% of an ordered result?